# Ruby - using pdftk to split a multi page pdf into many single page pdf's?

Tags: ruby, pdf, pdftk

I have tried using a gem called docsplit and got nothing but errors; even when trying the documentation examples, they wouldnt work on my windows machine.

I ran across a blog post giving me hope that this could be done in `pdftk`:
[here](http://ram-headerlabs.blogspot.com/2013/11/spliting-multiple-pages-single-pdf-into_14.html)

I have a pdf named `multi_page.pdf`

I need to split `multi_page.pdf` into **many** *single page* PDF's and output the many single page PDF's in a sub directory called `destination`

here is where I am, and its definitely not working

```
source_path = 'C:\Users\ALilland\Documents\split_test\one_page\destination'
source_file = 'C:\Users\ALilland\Documents\split_test\one_page\multi_page.pdf'
FileUtils.cd(source_path)
`pdftk #{source_file} burst output page_%02d.pdf`
```

Comment: Tried your code on Ubuntu and it works ok. Please pass the errors you get if any present

Comment: i just got it to work doing %x(pdftk C:\\Users\\ALilland\\Documents\\split_test\\one_page\\multi_page.pdf burst)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try it using the `combine_pdf` gem:

```
require 'combine_pdf'

pages = CombinePDF.load("my_pdf.pdf").pages;
i = 0
pages.each do |page|
   pdf = CombinePDF.new
   pdf << page
   pdf.save("#{i}.pdf")
   i+=1
end
```

The `combine_pdf` gem (I'm the author) is a native Ruby solution, so you don't have to worry about `pdftk`'s installation and requirements.

Comment: so much cleaner than pdftk thank you for writing it!

Comment: How is the performance of this vs Ruby Vips? https://github.com/libvips/ruby-vips Will it split a 100 page pdf no problem?  I've had issues with ImageMagick performance splitting PDFs.

Comment: @fatfrog - I have no idea. It would be great if you could test it and post something about it 

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use [hexapdf](https://hexapdf.gettalong.org/)

```
$ gem install hexapdf
$ hexapdf modify -i 1-10 input.pdf output.pdf
```

where `1-10` is a PAGE SPECIFICATION according to their [docs](https://hexapdf.gettalong.org/documentation/hexapdf.1.html#modify). It says "pages 1-10" will be in the output PDF.